# Merging two columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'am working on attendance project. In that i am storing students who are absent on the particular date in the table 'attendance' with fields -> sno,rollno,subject_code,date.    And if all the students are present then i will store subject_code, date and rollno as NULL which means'all students are present'

```
------|--------|------------|-----------|  
sno   |rollno  |subject_code|  date     |  
1     | 1234   |  a110      | 12-12-2012|
2     | 1235   |  a110      | 12-12-2012|
3     | 1235   |  a111      | 14-12-2012|
```

iam taking the students details from table 'students' with fields -> rollno,name

```
  |--------|-------|
  | rollno |  name |
  | 1234   |  xyz  |
  | 1235   |  abc  |
  | 1236   |  mno  |
  | 1237   |  qrs  |
```

Now I want to list the students attendance such that output should be like this for particular date assume list for the date "12-12-2012"

```
list of "12-12-2012" for subject a110   list of "14-12-2012" for subject a111
     |-------|------|---------|           |-------|------|---------|      
     |rollno | name | status  |           |rollno | name | status  |  
     | 1234  | xyz  | Absent  |           | 1234  | xyz  | Present |  
     | 1235  | abc  | Absent  |           | 1235  | abc  | Absent  |  
     | 1236  | mno  | Present |           | 1236  | mno  | Present |  
     | 1237  | qrs  | Present |           | 1237  | qrs  | Present |
```

Please Help me..

Comment: what happen if multiple student are absent on same day? are multiple rows on first table?

Comment: students who are absent are added in the attendance table for that day and the subject

Comment: Can you update your sample to show that case? two student Absent on same day?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to find out which student doesnt have a row in the attendance table. (those where present)

```
 SELECT s.rollno,
        s.name, 
        CASE WHEN a.rollno IS NULL THEN 'Present'
             ELSE 'Absent'
        END as status
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN attendance a
       ON s.rollno = a.rollno
```